# Data paste in piecewise table

Tags: piecewise

How can I paste data copied from several lines into a piecewise table, without pasting it in a single cell?

[image: 1st Step]

[image: 2nd Step]

[image: 3rd Step]

Comment: As far as I know the copied expression needs to be in `GridBox` format to paste into multiple selected Placeholders, meaning that what you request may be impossible without intermediate conversion.

This at least works, though it may not be applicable to your situation:  `Table[{a^i}, {i, 3}] // Grid`.  Note that you must select only the column of vales and not the entire grid or it will still fail; this may be accomplished by drag-selection from *within* the column rather than from outside it.